How to check what percentage of a column is made up of certain rows
I have a CSV file that is too large to be opened in Excel. In this file, I am trying to see how much of each column's sum is from rows 1, 47:56, and 156:158. This does NOT include the first two columns of the file. There are also headers for both the rows and columns. The file is made up of about 22,000 columns and 210 rows.
I am trying to see which columns get more than >.1% of their total sums from the mentioned rows, and then delete those columns.
I have been using vroom rather than readr when loading the file due to how large it is.
Example file setup:
  H e a d e r           A1    A2    A3    A4    A5    A6
H    1    sample a     1     0     0     13    0     9
e    2    sample b     4     0     0     8     312   24
a    3    sample c     0     20    0     49    0     17
d    4    sample d     2     0     213   18    56    3
e    5    sample e     5     4     0     10    94    62
r    6    sample f     9     87    0     2     33    90


Code:
library(dplyr)

library(vroom)


myData <- vroom("File.csv")

myData$newRow <- 100*(colSums(myData[-1, -2])/rowSums(myData[1, 47:56, 156:158]))

I was trying to create a new row with the percentage from (each column's sum EXCEPT 1 and 2)/(sum called rows). And here is the latest error message I have received, and the one that I am having trouble understanding:
> myData$newRow <- 100*(colSums(myData[-1, -2])/rowSums(myData[1, 47:56, 156:158]))
Error:
! Assigned data `100 * ...` must be compatible with existing data.
✖ Existing data has 200 rows.
✖ Assigned data has 21941 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning message:
In drop && length(xo) == 1L :
  'length(x) = 3 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

You're not far off the answer, but there are a few issues with your current approach:

myData$newRow <- will create a new column, not a new row. I would suggest something like myData[nrow(myData)+1, ] <- to add new rows to the data.
when selecting the rows or columns from the data frame using [ ] the different ranges should be wrapped in c(), otherwise R thinks they are different dimensions.
you should use colSums() in both calculations, rowSums will get a total for the rows, which is not what is needed here.
The column subset c(-1, -2) should be in both calculations (and on the left hand side of <-).
The division calculation is in the wrong order.

So:
myData[nrow(myData) + 1, c(-1, -2)] <- 100 * colSums(myData[c(1, 47:56, 156:158), c(-1, -2)]) / colSums(myData[, c(-1, -2)])


Thank you! I initially received an error that seemed to be resolved by wrapping the right hand side of <- with the as.list() function. The percentages were higher than I expected, but that may very well be a problem with the approach/user and not the code haha. Thank you for your help/corrections, I appreciate it!

Hello again, I was experimenting with why the percentages are high and wanted to check by comparing each row individually instead of all at once. However, when I checked, I noticed that now each of the new values are sequentially growing higher, as though they are adding the previous to whatever new value/% is created per column, ie. 1.72540927, 5.622141728, 5.686898066, 6.544566545, 6.654659586, 6.775547353, etc. I only changed the c() section of the code, so:
myData[nrow(myData) + 1, c(-1, -2)] <- as.list(100 * colSums(myData2[1]) / colSums(myData2[, c(-1,- 2)]))

Do you mean that you are running the new code after running the original code? This would indeed add new rows to the data and would affect the calculations each time. Maybe don't add the result to a new row of the data but keep it in a separate vector (percentages <- 100 * colSums(myData[c(1, 47:56, 156:158), c(-1, -2)]) / colSums(myData[, c(-1, -2)])). If this is not the problem, then I would suggest you submit a new question, preferably with some sample data to show exactly what is happening.

I restarted rather than running after the original, thank you though! Wasn't sure if it was something simple I was doing wrong that would be easy to see. I'll create a new question, thanks!

1. Do yourself a favor and make it easier to read. Create two vectors for rows and columns that contain the hot data.

> m_rows <- c(1, 3, 5)  ## `c(1, 47:56, 156:158)` w/ your original data
> a_cols <- grep('^A\\d+', names(dat))  ## or `c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6")`

2. Get away from Excel thinking to add rows with sums. Create a vector that contains the result, in this case the columns to keep.

keep <- colSums(dat[m_rows, a_cols])/colSums(dat[, a_cols]) < .25  ## <.001 in your case

Now you can easily subset your data,
> keep
   A1    A2    A3    A4    A5    A6 
FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE 

> dat[, keep]
   Header2 A1  A3 A6
1 sample_a  1   0  9
2 sample_b  4   0 24
3 sample_c  0   0 17
4 sample_d  2 213  3
5 sample_e  5   0 62
6 sample_f  9   0 90

and write it to disk as .csv.
write.csv(dat[, keep], file='foo.csv', row.names=FALSE)

By the way, for large data, data.table::fread and data.table::fwrite are much faster than resd.csv and write.csv.

Data:
> dput(dat)
structure(list(Header1 = 1:6, Header2 = c("sample_a", "sample_b", 
"sample_c", "sample_d", "sample_e", "sample_f"), A1 = c(1L, 4L, 
0L, 2L, 5L, 9L), A2 = c(0L, 0L, 20L, 0L, 4L, 87L), A3 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 213L, 0L, 0L), A4 = c(13L, 8L, 49L, 18L, 10L, 2L), A5 = c(0L, 
312L, 0L, 56L, 94L, 33L), A6 = c(9L, 24L, 17L, 3L, 62L, 90L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))


Hello! Thank you for your advice, I appreciate it! I am trying this version out - with the new added complication of using the average of the rows for the percent instead - but have noticed that with the a_cols line, it returns as integer(0), which I don't understand. Is it meant to do that, or have I erred in adjusting the code to my data? I changed the "A" to "ASV," as that is how mine are actually titled - ASV1, ASV2, ASV3, and so on. Did I misunderstand that part?
Code I'm using:
a_cols <- grep('^ASV\\d+', names(myData))

@Jay Hmm this is weird. Try grep('ASV\\d+', c('foo', 'bar', 'ASV1', 'ASV2', 'ASV3')), or grep('ASV\\d+', c('foo', 'bar', 'ASV1', 'ASV2', 'ASV3'), value=TRUE). Maybe a typo? Or what does actually names(myData) return? You could of course also do a_cols <- c("A1", "A2",...)
